# Reset array in a nested loop while saving array at each iteration

Tags: python, arrays, loops, numpy, copy

I am running some simulations that take a numpy array as input, continue for several iterations until some condition is met (stochastically), and then repeat again using the same starting array.  Each complete simulation starts with the same array and the number of steps to complete each simulation isn't known beforehand (but it's fine to put a limit on it, `maxt`).

I would like to save the array (`X`) after each step through each simulation, preferably in a large multi-dimensional array.  Below I'm saving each simulation output in a list, and saving the array with `copy.copy`.  I appreciate there are other methods I could use (using tuples for instance) so is there a more efficient method for doing this in Python?

Note: I appreciate this is a trivial example and that one could vectorize the code below.  In the actual application being used, however, I have to use a loop as the stochasticity is introduced in a more complicated manner.

```
import numpy as np, copy
N = 10
Xstart = np.zeros(N)
Xstart[0] = 1

num_sims = 3
prob = 0.2
maxt = 20

analysis_result = []

for i in range(num_sims):

    print("-------- Starting new simulation --------")
    t = 0
    X = copy.copy(Xstart)

    # Create a new array to store results, save the array
    sim_result = np.zeros((maxt, N))
    sim_result[t,:] = X

    while( (np.count_nonzero(X) < N) & (t < maxt) ):
        print(X)

        # Increment elements of the array stochastically
        X[(np.random.rand(N) < prob)] += 1

        # Save the array for time t
        sim_result[t,:] = copy.copy(X)
        t += 1

    print(X)
    analysis_result.append(sim_result[:t,:])
```

Comment: Did you consider making `analysis_result = np.zeros((num_sims, maxt, N))`? And did you check without using copy.copy?

Comment: Good point about making `analysis_result` larger.  No, I haven't changed `copy.copy` as that wouldn't save the result correctly - since these are numpy arrays (and they're mutable) the results will not be correct (it will just be a copy of the final array for each row of `sim_results`).

Comment: Fair. Intuitively would prefer to use np.copy then the two aliases for numpy and the double copy.copy :)